# Core Data message Unable to find an instance of NSValueTransformer registered for the name: NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName

Tags: core-data, nskeyedunarchiver

I am using Core Data to store NSAttributedString and use a transformable field to store the data.  However I get the message below from Core Data, although everything seems to work fine.  How can I get rid of the message or can I safely ignore it.

```
Unable to find an instance of NSValueTransformer registered for the name: NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName
```

Comment: Have you explicitly set a transformer name?

Comment: Yes its 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName', which seems odd now that I think about it.  Funny that it works at all with this name!

Comment: Remove the custom name to use a default serialiser.

Comment: @Wain thanks that fixes it.  Not sure how I ended up with this.

Comment: I'll add an answer, but it might just be better to delete this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the transformer class name has been set to `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`, and that a class with that name doesn't exist.

You'll either need to remove that class name and a default serialiser will be used or you need to create that class and have it perform some custom archiving.